# Use Firebase to detect iOS-Jailbreak

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have seen inside my Firebase Console, that Firebase Crashlytics seems to be able to detect, whether the device is jailbroken or not.

[image: Crashlytics-Report]

Is there a function/way to read this value inside my app to use it for other use-cases?

I didn't find something about it in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I am also curious to know how accurate this is and if there are any false positives, or false negatives.